# Serving static content from Spring boot results in 404 whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a question regarding Spring boot. I'd like to serve static content, and I have made a `ResourceHandler` in my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebApplicationConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public FileSystem fileSystem() {
        FileSystem fileSystem = new LocalFileSystem();
        return fileSystem;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        LOG.info("Serving static content from " + fileSystem().getBaseFolder());
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/storage/**").addResourceLocations("file:///" + fileSystem().getBaseFolder());
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

}
```

My application runs in a Docker container and I mounted the host' volume /myapplication/storage. When I ssh into my Docker container, I see that this volume is present and that reflects the `fileSystem().getBaseFolder()`-call. This directory is also writable, but it is outside my project.

The LOG statement is executed:
`"Serving static content from /myapplication/storage"`, so I know this code is being executed as well.

Further information that can be relevant is:

- It is a Linux environment.
- Write permissions are correct for that folder.
- Folder exists and is writable and readable.
- I have a couple of `@RestController`'s annotated. All the methods in there start with `@RequestMapping("/api/")`, so there is no mapping that starts with /static.
- Already dropped off the /// in front of file:, but without any effect.

Does anyone know how do I make those files in that folder readable. It is always returning a 404. The folder must be outside of the project, so don't suggest to put it into `/resources/static`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try dropping the extra slashes from `file:///`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I have tried that already without effect. I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made a beginners mistake. As @chrylis mentioned in the comments, I removed the `///` in front of `file:`. I did some test runs, and as it appeared, I had the following entry in my `application.properties`: `myapplication.picture.basefolder=/myapplication/storage`. It missed a trailing slash. So I updated it to `myapplication.picture.basefolder=/myapplication/storage/`, and my problem was fixed.

Comment: Man...thanks! it's the second time that I loose hours for this slash problem :-)